# CSS Search box won't float left

Tags: html, css, shopify, search-box

I have this

```
            <td width="312" valign="center" height="157" background="{{ 'BT_S3.png' | asset_url }}">
             <div style="width:95%; text-align: left; height:52px; background-image:url('{{ 'search_bar.png' | asset_url }}');" float="left">
            <form action="/search" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" src="{{ 'search_bar.png' | asset_url }}" />
            <input type="image" value="Search"  src="{{ 'search_button.png' | asset_url }}"  />
            </form>
            </div>
            </td>
```

This is my HTML for my search box located at 
http://clarkbetty.myshopify.com/#
Password: betweu

I would like the search button to float so that the search box and button are on the same line. I have tried a lot of things but nothing works. Can someone help?

Comment: am using chrome, they are in the same line

Answer (score 1):

You should add `style="float:left"` to both the text box and the button elements.

```
<input type="text" [...] style="float:left" />
<input type="image" [...] style="float:left" />
```

Also note that it's even better to put these rules into a css file instead and refer to these elements by their ids or classes.

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be to apply relative positioning to the wrapping `form` element, and use absolute positioning on the inner controls (search field and button inputs) to control their layout inside of it.

something along these lines:

```css
form {
    position: relative;
}
input[type='text'],
input[type='image'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
input[type='text'] {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
input[type='image'] {
    right: 0;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You were great help!

Comment: you're most welcome. it is of courtesy to up-vote a useful answer, or mark it accepted, case it solved your problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<input type="text" name="q" src="{{ 'search_bar.png' | asset_url }}" />
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" style="float:left;" name="q" src="{{ 'search_bar.png' | asset_url }}" />
```

float:left has to be inside style attribute.

Comment: I did so and it did not change anything.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the name of the background image tricked me. You have to add style attribute to the line with the input . I'm editing my post.